# Load Torrent in VB.NET with Monotorrent

Tags: vb.net, torrent, monotorrent

im making a simply app to download torrent files, using MonoTorrent. But i cant load the torrent properly, and I've looked all available information.

That's the code im using:

```
    Imports MonoTorrent.BEncoding
Imports MonoTorrent.Client
Imports MonoTorrent.Client.Tracker
Imports MonoTorrent.Common
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class
Module BitTorrentAnnounceReader
    Sub main()

        'load Torrentfile
        Dim TorrentFile As torrent = ("D:\youtorrent.torrent")
        Console.WriteLine(TorrentFile.Name)

        'generate annouce paramters
        'since we simluate a BitTornado Client double check PeerID and Key Paramter
        Dim AnnounceParameter As New AnnounceParameters
        AnnounceParameter.BytesLeft = TorrentFile.Size
        AnnounceParameter.BytesUploaded = 0
        AnnounceParameter.BytesDownloaded = 0
        AnnounceParameter.Port = 12224
        AnnounceParameter.InfoHash = TorrentFile.InfoHash
        AnnounceParameter.PeerId = "T03I-----" & GenerateTorrentClientKeys(11, 1)
        AnnounceParameter.ClientEvent = TorrentEvent.Started

        'a torrentfile can have more than one url, we use only the first one
        'the url should have http to work for this example
        Dim AnnounceUrl As String = TorrentFile.AnnounceUrls.Item(0).Item(0).ToString
        Console.WriteLine(AnnounceUrl)

        'the full announceurl that will fired to tracker
        'we are simulating a BitTorando Client
        Dim FullAnnounceUrl As String = CreateAnnounceString(AnnounceParameter, AnnounceUrl, GenerateTorrentClientKeys(6))

        'building a webrequest for tracker request; some silly line look at comments on
        'MonoTorrent.Client.Tracker.HTTPTracker.Announce
        Dim req As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(FullAnnounceUrl), HttpWebRequest)
        req.KeepAlive = False
        req.Proxy = New WebProxy

        'we want to simulate a BitTornado Client, so http headers
        req.UserAgent = "User-Agent: BitTornado/T-0.3.18"

        'to simulate full client we need also gzip but for better usage we dont use it
        ' req.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")
        ' If (resp.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("gzip")) Then
        ' Str = New IO.Compression.GZipStream(Str, IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress)

        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = req.GetResponse
        Dim fs As Stream = WebResponseToStream(response)

        Dim peers As List(Of Peer) = AnnounceGetPeerList(fs)
        Console.WriteLine("Tracker returned:" & peers.Count)
        For Each PeerInfo As Peer In peers
            Console.WriteLine(PeerInfo.ConnectionUri.Host & ":" & PeerInfo.ConnectionUri.Port)
        Next

        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Generate a random key depending on which TorrentClient to simulate
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="len"></param>
    ''' <param name="keys"></param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Function GenerateTorrentClientKeys(ByVal len As Integer, Optional ByVal keys As Integer = 1) As String

        Dim Chars() As String = {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"}
        'Chars[0] = uTorrent Keys
        'Chars[1] = BitTornado Keys
        Dim str As String = ""
        Dim r As New System.Random()

        For i = 1 To len
            str &= Chars(keys).Substring(r.Next(1, Chars(keys).Length), 1)
        Next

        Return str

    End Function
    ''' <summary>
    ''' A simple way of parsing a bencoded peerlist. it will autodecode compact mode request
    ''' you can find the full announce parser in the orignal file:
    ''' 
    ''' MonoTorrent.Client.Tracker.HTTPTracker.HandleAnnounce
    ''' http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/bitsharp/src/MonoTorrent/MonoTorrent.Client/Tracker/HTTPTracker.cs
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="fs"></param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Function AnnounceGetPeerList(ByVal fs As Stream) As List(Of Peer)
        'you can also use a file with a torrenrequest
        'Dim reader As New RawReader(IO.File.Open("file.req", IO.FileMode.Open), False)

        'decode the bencoded stream
        Dim dictionary As BEncodedDictionary = BEncodedValue.Decode(Of BEncodedDictionary)(fs)

        Dim peers As New List(Of Peer)
        For Each keypair In dictionary
            Select Case keypair.Key.ToString
                Case "interval"
                    'MsgBox TimeSpan.FromSeconds(int.Parse(keypair.Value.ToString())); 
                    'MsgBox(keypair.Value.ToString)
                Case "peers"
                    If TypeOf keypair.Value Is BEncodedList Then
                        peers.AddRange(Peer.Decode(DirectCast(keypair.Value, BEncodedList)))
                    ElseIf TypeOf keypair.Value Is BEncodedString Then
                        peers.AddRange(Peer.Decode(DirectCast(keypair.Value, BEncodedString)))
                    End If
                Case Else
                    'MsgBox("HttpTracker - Unknown announce tag received:" & keypair.Key.ToString() & keypair.Value.ToString())
            End Select
        Next

        Return peers
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Original CreateAnnounceString is private only and we need to modify it a little bit; this the old one out of svn
    ''' they have created here a better function that uses UriQueryBuilder but its oversized here
    ''' 
    ''' MonoTorrent.Client.Tracker.HTTPTracker.CreateAnnounceString
    ''' http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/bitsharp/src/MonoTorrent/MonoTorrent.Client/Tracker/HTTPTracker.cs?revision=141866
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="parameters"></param>
    ''' <param name="Uri">AnnounceURL of the TorrentFile</param>
    ''' <param name="Key">a radon key paramter</param>
    ''' <returns>url to use with a WebRequest</returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Function CreateAnnounceString(ByVal parameters As AnnounceParameters, ByVal Uri As String, ByVal Key As String) As String
        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder(256)

        'base.LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
        ' FIXME: This method should be tidied up. I don't like the way it current works
        sb.Append(Uri)
        sb.Append(If(Uri.Contains("?"), "&"c, "?"c))
        sb.Append("info_hash=")
        sb.Append(parameters.InfoHash.UrlEncode())
        sb.Append("&peer_id=")
        sb.Append(parameters.PeerId)
        sb.Append("&port=")
        sb.Append(parameters.Port)
        If parameters.SupportsEncryption Then
            sb.Append("&supportcrypto=1")
        End If
        If parameters.RequireEncryption Then
            sb.Append("&requirecrypto=1")
        End If
        sb.Append("&uploaded=")
        sb.Append(parameters.BytesUploaded)
        sb.Append("&downloaded=")
        sb.Append(parameters.BytesDownloaded)
        sb.Append("&left=")
        sb.Append(parameters.BytesLeft)
        sb.Append("&compact=1")
        ' Always use compact response
        sb.Append("&numwant=")
        sb.Append(100)
        If Not Uri.Contains("&key=") AndAlso Not Uri.Contains("?key=") Then
            sb.Append("&key=")
            ' The 'key' protocol, used as a kind of 'password'. Must be the same between announces
            sb.Append(Key)
        End If
        If parameters.Ipaddress IsNot Nothing Then
            sb.Append("&ip=")
            sb.Append(parameters.Ipaddress)
        End If

        ' If we have not successfully sent the started event to this tier, override the passed in started event
        ' Otherwise append the event if it is not "none"
        'if (!parameters.Id.Tracker.Tier.SentStartedEvent)
        '{
        '    sb.Append("&event=started");
        '    parameters.Id.Tracker.Tier.SendingStartedEvent = true;
        '}
        If parameters.ClientEvent <> TorrentEvent.None Then
            sb.Append("&event=")
            sb.Append(parameters.ClientEvent.ToString().ToLower())
        End If


        Return sb.ToString()
    End Function
    ''' <summary>
    ''' HttpWebResponse and GetResponseStream dont gives use a full readable stream so we must convert it
    ''' 
    ''' Look at: MonoTorrent.Client.Tracker.HTTPTracker.DecodeResponse
    ''' http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/bitsharp/src/MonoTorrent/MonoTorrent.Client/Tracker/HTTPTracker.cs
    ''' or
    ''' http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/232436-download-binary-file-http#post949811
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="response"></param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Function WebResponseToStream(ByVal response As HttpWebResponse) As Stream

        Dim responseStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream
        Dim fs As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(256)

        Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(4095) {}
        Dim length As Integer = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, 4096)

        While length > 0
            fs.Write(buffer, 0, length)
            length = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, 4096)
        End While

        fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)

        Return fs
    End Function
End Module
```

The problem only appears in the load file .torrent part:

```
Dim TorrentFile As **torrent** = ("D:\youtorrent.torrent")
```

Vb.net throws me an error of "Type expected 'on the text *torrent*. there any solution? Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Dim TorrentFile As torrent = Torrent.Load("D:\youtorrent.torrent")
```

Comment: I believe it's throwing that error because your vb.net project is targeting a different .NET framework than the Monotorrent dll you're referencing. I tested a project and saw the same issue, then switched my vb project to target .NET 2.0 and it recognizes it.

Comment: I'm having the same problem after changing to NET version 2.0: http://i.imgur.com/DGvj0t2.png

Comment: Are your MonoTorrent Imports highlighted as unrecognizable or not being used? If you delete the Imports, then add them back, does it seem to recognize it until you run, then it errors again? If Yes to any of those questions, then it's something to do with the dll not be recognized as compatible. Is 'Copy Local' for the MonoTorrent reference set to True or False?

Comment: You were right, I'm back to doing the project for .NET 2.0 and now everything seems to work perfectly, but the code does not seem to download any .torrent file